# mysql function does not exist when I call it from the terminal

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to store some data in a file using a function I created.  When I use the command from within mysql:

`select threadRef, allExpertPosts(threadRef) as 'expertPosts' from chronicweb_data.threads order by threadRef limit 5;`

it works fine.  However, when I call it from the terminal:

```
mysql -p --batch -B -e 'select threadRef, allExpertPosts(threadRef) as 'expertPosts' from chronicweb_data.threads order by threadRef limit 5' > someThreadsOfOnlyExperts.txt
```

it returns

> ERROR 1305 (42000) at line 1: FUNCTION allExpertPosts does not exist

Why can't it find my function?

EDIT: it worked when I added the database.  Thanks!

Comment: Its probably because there is no default database selected in the second case. Try `{database_name}.allExpertPosts(...)`.

Comment: You can specify the database with `mysql db_name ....`